# build, buildmode=c does not give header file

Tags: go, go-build

I'm trying to build a Go package with the build flag `-buildmode=c-shared`. I'm expecting to get two files `myfile.so` and `myfile.h`. However, I'm only getting the `.so` file. Why is this and how can I fix it?

The full command I am running is:

`go build -o myfile.so -buildmode=c-shared myfile.go`

I found my "instructions" [here](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) as I am planning on calling `myfile` from Python.

This is my Go code:

```
package main


import (
    "C"
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)



func call_request(arg1, arg2, arg3 string) {
// simple golang code to submit a http post request
    }

func main () {
}
```

This is a basic summary of my code, without posting my whole code. However, it may be useful to note that running the example in the link above created a `.so` and `.h` file.

Comment: If you don’t export anything, there’s no reason to create a header file.

Comment: @JimB that's it, thanks. I need to use the //export comment to annotate functions I wish to make accessible to other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JimB said, the issue was there was not a header file:

**Updated code:**

```
package main


import (
    "C"
    "bytes"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)


//export call_request
func call_request(arg1, arg2, arg3 string) {
// simple golang code to submit a http post request
    }

func main () {
}
```